# Using AWS Mobile Hub to get a working sign in

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-mobilehub

I was under the impression that AWS Mobile Hub built out things for you in the sample app.

But I see on the resources page that it uses a AWS Cognito which I defined an auth and unauth roles.  The app builds but I keep getting this when I try to login:

[image]

I have sign in enabled:

[image]

In this identity pool I have greated a unauth and auth roles. Then in Mobile Hub downloaded the code but still can't get login working. What am I missing?

Comment: Samples Present in the link : https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples can answer your questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using Custom login, it means that you want to authenticate the users against your backend or developer authenticated identities. This is how it works:

1. The end user will provide credentials(username and password) on your iOS App.
2. App will call your backend to verify the credentials.
3. Backend will call [GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html) API of Amazon Cognito for that end-user (using the username)
4. Cognito will return an identityId associated with that username and a OpenId Connect Token to your backend and it will passed back to the Android App.
5. Cognito SDK will use this token to call Amazon STS to get AWS credentials for the end user.

I would highly encourage you to follow our [blog post](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx3E3NJURV1LNV1/Integrating-Amazon-Cognito-using-developer-authenticated-identities-An-end-to-en) and the [developer guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/developer-authenticated-identities/), it explains this flow in depth. As always, if you have any questions please feel free to ask.

Thanks.

Comment: True but I want to use Lamba as my backend as I am migrating to AWS since Parse went/is going down. I'm confused about the iOS app on my device to Lamba to Cognito and back. And yep reading all the blogs and stuff (lots of great things going on in AWS and I've only been at it a week)

Comment: I should say my goals/flow is this: 1. User has app on phone and goes to register and enters username and password. 2. Goes to Lamba to check if username is already taken, if not registers by using Cognito. If it is returns an error. 3. After registraion user is now authenticated and app uses aws api's and calls DynamoDB and S3 directly. Is this the correct approach?

Comment: Cognito will not register users, you will be registering users in your Lambda function against some database and then you get credentials to access S3/DynamoDB  from Cognito for this user.

Comment: I will pose another question and reference it here.

Comment: I'm hoping this is a secure/okay flow: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35356570/665557

Comment: I answered your other post.

Comment: Yeah I have it going in the right direction with Lanbda. So all is good.