# Creating a user/developer defined login for AWS iOS using iOS SDK Cognito Lambda and DynamoDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

I am trying to figure out if this is the "proper"/current/correct flow for developing a user/developer defined login credential for iOS using AWS.

(I am migrating from Parse to AWS so only been reading AWS for a week).

1. Download, install, and build an iOS app for registering users (say email and password (this is done and the app shows a UITextField for email and password and accessible in the UIViewController)). Also iOS SDK via Cocoapods is installed and available.
2. Create an identity pool with an unauth and auth roles that access the different services. So unauth technically will access what they need. Unauth accesses DynamoDB full access and Cognito. Auth adds in s3 and sns.  This is done. Does Lambda needed to be added? (all set up in IAM and Cognito).
3. Use Lambda to create functions to be called from the iOS device to see if a user is register in DynamoDB.
4. If user is registered and matched against Lambda's call to DynamoDB, use Cognito to switch from unauth role to auth.
5. Now user is authenticated and can get access to S3, SNS and other service.

Is there a better way to do this?  Is this secure?  Have a little trouble with steps 3 to 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are calling Lambda function from the app, you need to add permission for that in IAM. 
Your flow looks good, just make sure you are calling [GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognitoidentity/latest/APIReference/API_GetOpenIdTokenForDeveloperIdentity.html) from your Lambda function. You might want to look into this [project](https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth) for references.

Comment: Yeah I have that project up and running and adapting it to iOS now. Thx.

Comment: Great to hear that you got it working. As always feel free to post in our forums or here if you have any questions.

Comment: I didn't even realize you had a full developer former but I will start posting there. Thx.

Comment: @cdub have you come finally with solution? I am migrating also from parse and having issues with 3-5 steps

Comment: @Neil I have kinda slowly getting there. I got this working (https://github.com/danilop/LambdAuth) and used that as a base to start with.  Now I'm working on the DynamoDB which is NoSQL (like Parse but Parse hid that from you) so the learning curve has been high

Comment: I got that Github working in AWS correctly then used the Lambda code as a base (in the folders there are index.js files which are good sample code).